# Why I got the wrong mean value in R?

Tags: r, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean of `-0.9643991` and `-0.6756494`, but for some reasons, the mean function returns the value of the first number; as shown below:

```
> a = -0.9643991
> b = -0.6756494
> mean(a, b)
[1] -0.9643991
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Read `?mean`. See the arguments that it takes.

Comment: Try: `mean(c(a,b))`

Comment: Thanks GKi . Your solution works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mean` takes the mean of its first argument, a vector. Additional arguments let you set preferences, which can depend on the class of the first argument, such as ignoring missing values. If you want the mean of `a` and `b`, you need to put them together in a vector, using `c()`. Like this:

```
mean(c(a, b))
```